# How to update a progress bar for a SQL query that doesn't return a status?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, phpmyadmin

How to put a progress bar in this code?
when the process start the progressbar will show and strat loading

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = connect()
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = ("Select * from user_acc where username= 'admin' and password='" & tbadminpass.Text & "' and position = 'Administrator'")
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dr.Read()
        If dr.HasRows Then

            If opd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                dbfile.Text = opd.FileName
                Dim myprocess As New Process
                myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
                myprocess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
                myprocess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\"
                myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
                myprocess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
                myprocess.Start()
                Dim mystream As StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
                Dim myreader As StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
                mystream.WriteLine("mysql -h " & My.Settings.dbserver & " -u " & My.Settings.dbuser & " --password=" & My.Settings.dbpass & " " & My.Settings.dbdatabase & " < " & dbfile.Text & "")
                mystream.Close()
                myprocess.WaitForExit()
                myprocess.Close()
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Restore Success!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Else
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "There is an Error while restoring database!", "Warning Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        Else
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Invalid Username/Password", "Please Check Your Credentials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "Unable to Connect to Server!!!", "Please Check Your Connection", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End Try
```

Comment: You cant progress something that has no incremental difference, like a remote resource, or an sql query. However, you can display a progress bar for the fun of it and set it to Marquee ect

Comment: A `ProgressBar` control is not magic. It is simply a visual representation of a ratio. It's up to you to calculate the ratio you want to display. It's important to understand the problem you're actually trying to solve. This has nothing to do with `ProgressBars`. The question is how can you MEASURE the progress of an operation. Think about that. That's for you to work out and attempt to implement if you can indeed work it out.

Comment: Sql injection alert! Don't concatenate strings to add parameters to command text. Use actual Parameters.

Comment: StreamWriter needs to be disposed use a `Using` block.